Does a Random Forest leaf give a specific output for a specific class in a multi class random forest
I am trying to understand the basics of random forest machine learning applied to vegetation classification. Do I understand correctly that the output/leaf node of each individual decision tree contains a single class?

Yes, the regularization which is typically done on decision trees which makes the leaves non-pure is not needed in random forests due to the structure of the algorithm.
